# Switching words in a for-loop string

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

In the code below, is there are way that I could change the 'nth' in the for loop into the particular term I am considering.

For example: Enter a value for the first term, Enter a value for the second term, Enter a value for the third term, and so on. As opposed to the line 'Enter a value for the nth term' every time the loop runs.

```
for _ in range (n):
    total += float (input ('Enter a value for the nth term: '))
```

Comment: `input ('Enter value {}'.format(_)`

Comment: @SuryaTej, that's a reasonable solution if the OP is satisfied with just printing the digits of `_`. But if they want to literally print the words "first", "second", etc, then that's not something that format can do on its own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a library called Inflect that does almost exactly this.

> [inflect.py](https://pypi.org/project/inflect/) - Correctly generate plurals, singular nouns, ordinals, indefinite articles; convert numbers to words.

```
import inflect
p = inflect.engine()

for x in range (n):
    total += float (input('Enter a value for the {} term: '.format(p.ordinal(x+1))))
```

Puts...

```
Enter a value for the 1st term: 
Enter a value for the 2nd term:
```

And so on. There is also a numbers-to-words function you should take a look a - does the same thing but will actually put the word in english rather than "1st".

Comment: The [`num2words`](https://github.com/savoirfairelinux/num2words) package is more specifically designed for this (e.g. `num2words(42, to='ordinal') -> forty-second`).